Vector math effect not displaying on my model?
I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to this 
However, my nodes look identical to the one in the youtube video yet I see no effect happening? I've also attached my nodes here


What do you mean by "no effect happening" ? No colour ? No bump ? No displacement ? Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?


And this is the youtube video (timestamp 2:30) I am trying to follow, I'm wondering if maybe he has something on the uv map? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIa45V86X3Y

There’s a lone Fraction node with no linked output in your setup. Are you sure that’s correct?

I'm not sure, I am trying to copy the shader that is shown in the youtube video and he didn't connect it at that point I don't believe. I'm just trying to get that striped effect that is shown on the video linked. My knowledge of shaders is quite small, i'm sorry.
